# Disable/Enable Multiple 'between' Date Slicers

Tags: button, powerbi-desktop, bookmarks

I've been tasked with creating a report that requires multiple date slicers. These date slicers will need to be 'between slicers' and will be filtering a simple data table (no aggregations). Some date columns will be blank as well, I will need to see those blanks, when disabling a slicer.

I've been asked to include a way to disable/nullify each, so that, for example, a particular end-user wants to use the report while filtering based off one of the three date slicers and doesn't want the other two to affect the report. Or maybe they only want to exclude one of the three slicers.

Best thing would be to have a check box/button for each date slicer that when checked, would disable that slicer.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

(below is a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSF9h.png)

My first thought was to use buttons and bookmarks with a default view and a view for each slicer when it is 'disabled'. I accomplished disabling by editing the individual interactions of the slicers, but then I realized that I can't disable multiple slicers, at once, this way. I can't use the combination of multiple buttons to get a singular view because I set the buttons to affect the bookmark in place, but I need a button that instead affects the actual date slicer ... or something to that effect.

Comment: Simplest option would be to enable the slicer header which includes a clear slicer button (eraser) when hovered over. This effectively clears any selection.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was able to find the exact solution I wanted by using the 'selected visuals' option when setting up bookmarks.